# Simple questions about the meaning of an argument

Tags: python, scrapy

So I am running this command 
`scrapy crawl dmoz -o items.json`
I just don't understand what -o mean. I have researched, but can't find it.
Does that mean output? I am not sure.

Thank You!

Comment: `-o` usually means save the output in a file and it is followed by the name of the file, i.e `'items.json`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I run `scrapy crawl -h` to get the options:

```
--output=FILE, -o FILE  dump scraped items into FILE (use - for stdout)
```

The complete help:

```
Run a spider

Options
=======
--help, -h              show this help message and exit
-a NAME=VALUE           set spider argument (may be repeated)
--output=FILE, -o FILE  dump scraped items into FILE (use - for stdout)
--output-format=FORMAT, -t FORMAT
                        format to use for dumping items with -o

Global Options
--------------
--logfile=FILE          log file. if omitted stderr will be used
--loglevel=LEVEL, -L LEVEL
                        log level (default: DEBUG)
--nolog                 disable logging completely
--profile=FILE          write python cProfile stats to FILE
--lsprof=FILE           write lsprof profiling stats to FILE
--pidfile=FILE          write process ID to FILE
--set=NAME=VALUE, -s NAME=VALUE
                        set/override setting (may be repeated)
--pdb                   enable pdb on failure
```